# Windows Image Deployment - WinPE - Execute Command After Server Image Deployment but Before WinPE Reboot

Tags: windows, windows-pe

Simplified version: Execute command in WinPE after server image deployment but before WinPE reboots.

Previous title: Windows Image Deployment - WinPE - Move Dynamically Generated XML via HTA to Windows Server

I have a custom ISO with a boot.wim and install.wim for deploying Windows Server to our environment.  Our environment does not allow DHCP and we have no static IPs available at build time so this will all be done with no internet connection during all phases of deployment.

We have a custom HTA form that generates an XML file based on user input and stores it on the RAMDisk during WinPE.  How can we move this XML file from the RAMDisk to the deployed Windows Server image?

Answer (score 0):

I am using MDT and I inject KMDF 1.11 into my Win7 image at the Postinstall phase.  I believe this would work for what you're attempting.

You may have a bit of trial and error to get the drive letter to populate.  I would hazard a guess that the target OS at the Postinstall phase is X:.